# regex detect word with 2+ number and 2+ character

Tags: javascript, java, regex, replace, regex-group

I need one regular expression for detect words with length 8 characters that contain 2+ numbers and 2+ characters (no special characters ).

I am near the solution and I did the regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/z33bUv/6) .

The problem are the words that contains one number that not should be releveant for my regex.

I discarded all words with characters that contain min 7 characters with `(?![A-Za-z]{7,})` .

I discarded all words with numbersthat contain min 7 numbers with `(?![\d]{7,})` .

And I discarded the words that contain min 2 numbers and 2 characters `(?=[a-zA-Z\d]{2})[A-Za-z\d]{8}`.

Why `vaff8loe` is matched?

I created this regular expression because after I hae to replace the entire word with ******* .
Like:

```
papave23 ciao il mio pin papaver1 è reeredji332ji con vaff8loe 1234567o 123t123t papavero 9o 123t123y
```

After with replace("regex","********")

```
********ciao il mio pin papaver1 è reeredji332ji con ******** 1234567o ******** papavero 9o ********
```

Comment: I'd use [`/\b(?=[a-z_]*\d[a-z_]*\d)(?=\d*[a-z_]\d*[a-z_])\w{8}\b/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/z33bUv/8)

Comment: Other interesting solution.. @bobblebubble you solution is very fast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 2 zero-width positive lookaheads:

```
(?=.*?[a-zA-Z].*?[a-zA-Z])    Must contain 2 ASCII letters
(?=.*?[0-9].*?[0-9])          Must contain 2 digits
[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}                Must be exactly 8 letters and/or digits
```

Add `^` and `$` if not using `matches()` for running the regex.

That means a full regex of:

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z].*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9].*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$
```

For best performance, replace the `.` pattern with a negative character class. In that case you might want to shorten it with a repeating non-capturing group:

```
(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2})
(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})
```

---

**UPDATE**

As question was updated to say that regex is needed to replace such words with *'s, the `^` and `$` anchors should be changed to `\b` word boundary patterns, and the negative character classes must be changed to only skip valid characters:

```java
s = s.replaceAll("\\b(?=(?:[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]){2})(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\\b", "********");
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lDj1vO/1) for demo.

Note that `vaff8loe` in the given example only contains 1 digit, so should not be replaced.

Comment: how you discarded _ ?

Comment: I need a regex/pattern for replace with *

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani Sorry, I don't understand. The regex will only match a string of exactly 8 letters and/or digits (`[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}`), so it doesn't allow underscores. There is nothing to discard.

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani Sorry, I don't understand. The question says nothing about *replacing* anything, only about *detecting* something.

Comment: sure, this is my fault because I noticed after that the regex not work for my case :/ .. sorry it is my inexperience

Answer (score 3):

In situations where you need to apply so many conditions to your parsing (word must have length == 8, 2+ alphabet characters, 2+ digit characters and no special characters), I think you should strive for solutions you can *read* instead of throwing everything inside a single complex regular expression.

Assuming that you use [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56173720/4262446) solution, your code would look like this:

```js
let s = "papave23 ciao il mio pin papaver1 è reeredji332ji con vaff8loe 1234567o 123t123t papavero 9o 123t123y";

s = s.replace(/\b(?=(?:[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]){2})(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\b/g, "********");

console.log(s);
```

It isn't immediately clear what you're doing here, and eventual bugs and/or changes to your logic would be hard to maintain. Instead, you could take advantage of the [function replacement parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters) to break down your rules. You'd then have something like this:

```js
let s = "papave23 ciao il mio pin papaver1 è reeredji332ji con vaff8loe 1234567o 123t123t papavero 9o 123t123y";

// The first regex filters only 8-length words
s = s.replace(/\b\w{8}\b/g, 
    function(fullMatch) {
      // .match() can return null if no match is found, 
      // so I'm accounting for this.
      const digitMatch = fullMatch.match(/\d/g) || [];
      const letterMatch = fullMatch.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g) || [];
      const specialCharMatch = fullMatch.match(/\[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g);

      if (digitMatch.length >= 2
       && letterMatch.length >= 2
       && specialCharMatch === null) {
        return "********";
       } else {
        return fullMatch;
       }
  });

console.log(s);
```

It's more verbose, but also more readable and debuggable.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use positive lookahead patterns to constrain the number of numbers and alphabets:

```
\b(?=(?:\w*\d){2}\w*)(?=(?:\w*[A-Za-z]){2}\w*)\w{8}\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/z33bUv/7

Comment: ``\w`` allows `_` underscores too, which is not allowed according to question.